# PowerShell keep text formatting when reading in a file

Tags: c#, powershell, pastebin

I believe this is a simple question, but I can't wrap my head around it. I want to do diagnostic commands in command shell on Windows. Like this:

```
   $cmd =  "ipconfig >> c:\test.txt"

   $message = Invoke-Expression($cmd)

   [String]$message = Get-Content c:\topsecret\testme.txt
```

Then I want to be able to read the file and keep the formatting and lastly publish it to pastebin via their API. I've tried, but I seem to lose the formatting no matter what I do. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This happens because of your casting. `Get-Content` returns an object array with a string object per line in the textfile. When you cast it to `[string]`, it joins the objects in the array. The problem is that you don't specify what to join the objects with (e.g. linebreak `(backtick)n`).

```
ipconfig >> test.txt

#Get array of strings. One per line in textfile
$message = Get-Content test.txt

#Get one string-object with linebreaks
$message = (Get-Content test.txt) -join "`n"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. This below did: 
(Get-Content test.txt) -join [Environment]::NewLine

Comment: Try `Get-Content test.txt -Raw` if you have PS 3.0+.

Comment: Splitting a file into lines by default is ... an interesting design decision.

Comment: @usr, is it? PowerShell is built around the concept of pipeline and processing as you go. Reading the whole file by default would keep you waiting + using unnecessary memory to load the whole file into memory before being able to do anything with it. There's a reason people like StreamReader in c# :)

Answer (score 29):

To read all the data as a single string with the line breaks embedded

```
$file = 'c:\testfiles\testfile.txt'

(IPconfig /all) > $file

[IO.File]::ReadAllText($file)
```

If you have V3, they added the -Raw parameter that will accomplish the same thing:

```
Get-Content $file -Raw
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast to an array of strings, maybe. Like this, for your last example:

```
$message = @(Get-Content c:\topsecret\testme.txt)
```

Or this for the second one:

```
$message = [string[]](ipconfig)
```