# Inconsistency in Write-Output "$obj" and directly printing $obj in Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is the dummy.json file

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
}
```

I'm reading the contents of this file to a variable and outputting them

```
C:> $obj = Get-Content .\dummy.json
C:> $obj
{
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2"
}
C:> Write-Host "$obj"
{       "key1":"value1",        "key2":"value2" }
```

I know that Get-Content doesn't preserve the line breaks and joins it by " ". [Powershell keep text formatting when reading in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041857/powershell-keep-text-formatting-when-reading-in-a-file)

But why is there an inconsistency in the above 2 outputs ? I guess `Write-Host` is doing its job correctly. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Hi, what about `Write-Host $obj` ?

Comment: @sodawillow Yeah works, got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `Get-Content` that joins the lines (its output is an array of strings), but you putting the variable in double quotes (`"$obj"`). You can avoid that by joining the lines yourself:

```
Write-Host ($obj -join "`n")
Write-Host ($obj | Out-String)
Write-Host $($OFS="`n"; "$obj")
```

Another option would be to read the file directly as a single string, e.g. like this (requires PowerShell v3 or newer):

```
$obj = Get-Content .\dummy.json -Raw
```

or like this:

```
$obj = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('.\dummy.json')
```

Comment: Cool, got it. So, my understanding of Get-Content and Write-Host was wrong. Thanks :)